# Zoom effect css3 stretch my image

Tags: css, zooming

I want to create this effect:

Image on hover gets more dark and zooms it a little. I have the effect but my initial image is stretchted. I don't know the background image size, only wants that the image zoom a little when user is hovering.

```
.highlight{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-transition: background-size 3s ease, background-color 3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-size 3s ease, background-color 3s ease;
    transition: background-size 3s ease, background-color 3s ease;
}

.highlight:hover{
    background-size: 120% 120%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -moz-transition: background-size 3s ease, background-color 3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-size 3s ease, background-color 3s ease;
    transition: background-size 3s ease, background-color 3s ease;
}

.highlight:hover:before{
    content: "";
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    -moz-transition: background-size 3s ease, background-color 3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-size 3s ease, background-color 3s ease;
    transition: background-size 3s ease, background-color 3s ease;
}

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
<div class="highlight" style="background-image:url(image-url)">
    <div class="content">
        <h3>Text</h3>
        <p class="large">More text text text</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
<div class="highlight" style="background-image:url(image-url2)">
    <div class="content">
        <h3>Text2</h3>
        <p class="large">More text text text2</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you look for?

```css
.highlight{
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center top;
  -moz-transition: background-size 3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-size 3s ease;
  transition: background-size 3s ease;
}
.highlight:hover{
  background-size: 120%;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -moz-transition: background-size 3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-size 3s ease;
  transition: background-size 3s ease;
}

.highlight:before{
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -moz-transition: background-color 3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 3s ease;
  transition: background-color 3s ease;
}
.highlight:hover:before{
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  -moz-transition: background-color 3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 3s ease;
  transition: background-color 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="highlight" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1100/700/nature/2/)">
    <div class="content">
        <h3>Text</h3>
        <p class="large">More text text text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost perfect!
I have this effect in two images together, sharging a 50% of the page width. Now, a "margin" appears in top and bottom. I will add a image to my post so you can see the example. I think the problem is that hightligh div is wrapped by a "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6" div.

Comment: @user1422434 That margin most likely belong to the `h3`, so if you add `h3 { margin: 0 }` to your CSS it should go away. If not, you need to post a code snippet where this happen so I can see what else it could be

Comment: Ok, The problem is that the image that I am using is 2200x1400 and your image is 600*400, if the image was higher maybe looks pretty

Comment: @user1422434 What if you change to this `background-position: center top;` ?

Comment: Looks pretty now! I found a class that have a height on my highlight and was causing the mayor issue :) Thanks